# Php, Zend framework and google calendar issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

My client has got 3 display screens, and she is updating her gym classes through google calendar, and the website is using zend framework updating the data.

Now the client is requesting fourth screen, so I'm trying to set up a developing environment. I set up a new database, a new sub domain and copied all the original sql database and the site code to the new domain.

The problem I have is that now if i put a new class in through google calendar, the new sql database/the copied 3 existing screens do not update any more. However the original database and screens are updating properly still.

Can someone please piont me to the right direction to make my developing environment work? What are the possibilities causing the data not updating? I'm new to zend framework, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks heaps
S:)

Comment: Have you made sure that the configurations in application.ini are correct for your local environment? Can you connect to your local database directly using the credentials in the config? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Hi Just, thanks for your reply. Where do I look for the application.ini? This is a live subdomain environment I am using, so the developing site and the new copied database are all on the server. Can I use google calendar and zend framwork to update two databases online? I've got a couple of error emails sending to admin but no errors from the developing site. The email from google calendar says Screen 02 cannot get Group One Fitness feed. Error: exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 500 Any help from you is greatly appreciated. S:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, it turns out it is the cron jobs setting in cpanel did the trick. I need to add the gdata_calendar.php for the new site into the cron jobs, and it is working now. Cheers, S